# Как поднять слетевшую сеть Ubuntu Server в Hyper-V?

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

Возникла проблема с сетью виртуальной машине с Ubuntu Server в Hyper-V
Ip VM 192.168.1.6, ip хоста 192.168.1.11

```
Starting LSB: Raise network interfaces
wait for auto /etc/network/... to be up
systemctl status ifup-wait-all-auto.service
Failed to start Wait for all "auto" /etc/network/ to be up for network-online.target
```

Сделал вот [это](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209832/debian-systemd-network-online-target-not-working) - не помогло

Не пингуется ни шлюз, ни хост

ifconfig выдает:

```
#   The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.6
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

В результате веб-сервер встал :(

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304571 не оно?

Comment: У меня нет такого файла /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf в сервере его и не должно быть вроде-бы.

Comment: Свежесозданная гостевая система в сеть входит нормально с динамическим ip, когда ставлю статический ip перестает ресолвить доменные имена, но пинги проходят и на внутренние и на внешние адреса.
Написано 51 минуту назад
Ответить

Прописывал, динамические и статические адреса, нашел совет в аналогичном случае по ссылке в первом сообщении. Удалил виртуальный сетевой адаптер и создал новый. В общем выяснилось, что win10 и hyper-v не при чем, т.к. в новой гостевой системе все работает. Остается ubuntu, но что с ней непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

При нормально работающей виртуализованной системе установите гостевые сервисы hyper-v, чтобы гипервизор адекватно воспринимал виртуалку, потом найдите файлик с описанием интерфейса(через `mc` например), там есть тот сетевой интерфейс, что отваливается. 
`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`(например он)
собственно зайдите в него и ручками `bootproto` поставьте в `static`, не удаляйте `uiid`, напишите все оставшиеся настройки, и все ок будет.